# Valgrind succeeds where standalone app fails (invalid pointer: ANSI C)

Tags: c, compilation, 64-bit, valgrind

While porting a 32-bit system (Solaris) to Linux (RHEL 6) on a 64-bit arch, one subsystem fails and coredumps because of an invalid pointer.  The application that fails on Linux is still being compiled in 32-bit format and makes intensive use of pointers.  In perticular, it fails on a realloc() instruction.

On its side, Valgrind is able to run the application but reports numerous issues (more than 40), some of which being:

```
"Invalid read of size 4", 
"Address 0x]SomeAddress] is 8 bytes before a block of size 12,600 alloc'd", 
"Address 0x[SomeAddress] is 16 bytes after a block of size 8 free'd",
"Address 0x[SomeAddress] is 12 bytes after a block of size 8 alloc'd at 
 0x[SomeAddress]: malloc (vg_replace_malloc.c:291)
```

and so on.

The problematic part of the code where the error occurs is this (sorry, I can't post the original code for security reasons):

```
if ((sysnodes = (vNodeTemp *) realloc(sysnodes, sysnodmax * sizeof(vNodeTemp))) == (vNodeTemp *)     NULL) {
         ...code 
}
```

The code is compiled using the -m32 option.   Do you think there are compilation switches/flags that could fix the problem or should I re-visit the source code?

Thanks.

Comment: Is `sysnodmax` always greater than 0 and never makes `sysnodmax*sizeof(vNoteTemp)` overflow?

Comment: That's not the way `realloc()` is supposed to be used. If `realloc()` fails, you leak memory. Also, `realloc()` returns a `void*`, which is implicitly cast to your pointer type, so don't explicitly cast. Other than that, there's nothing obviously wrong with your code. Possible problems to look for in the rest of the code: -do you use a custom memory allocator? -was the pointer passed to `realloc()` invalid (wild pointer, already free'd?)

Comment: @user3772839 A program can easily run for 20 years if the errors it performs do no harm. But when you move it to another system where the errors actually do harm, you have to fix it. So you need to revisit the code - start by fixing the 1. error that valgrind shows you. Note that a long on linux is still 4 byte if you compile the application as 32 bit - regardless of it being run on a 64 bit architecture. (but `long` will be 8 byte if you compile it as 64 bit)

Comment: Acutally, the program is compiled on x86-64 but using the -m32 option so long variables are still 4 bytes.  The trail of a custom memory allocator might be interesting, will look into it, there are some clues leading to this.